# Classifying question as duplicate

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, duplicate-questions

What is StackOverflow's definition of ***duplicate*** question?

I noticed that there are many questions marked as duplicate just because its have the same answer. But the question with same answer doesn't always means that the question is also the same right?

Lets say I have two questions, for example:

*"Who is the richest man in the world?"*

*"Who is the founder of Microsoft?"*

We all know that these questions (may) point to the same answer. But as we can see, the questions is totally different. So, is this considered as duplicate too?

Example of ambiguously *"duplicate"* question: [Why do == comparisons with Integer.valueOf(String) give different results for 127 and 128?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20877086/confusion-in-method-integer-valueofstring) (*has been re-open*)

Comment: Let's not get *too* broad, here.  Link to what example you have of this.

Comment: Actually, I may as well, since I was going to post a discussion about it anyway - [are you talking about this question?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20877086/1079354)

Comment: @Makoto yes, it is of many questions that I noticed. I've updated the post

Comment: It has little to do with the phrasing of the question. "How do you add two numbers in C?" can be phrased many different ways, but the correct answer to all of them can be found in a single post that says "a = 1 + 1;". Certainly occasional mistakes are made, but the vast majority of the time they're actual duplicates; questions that are closed by mistake can be reopened.

Comment: Yeah, I've voted to reopen that question as well. The answer to both questions might use the same method, but the newer question needs a lot more in depth explanation than the supposed original duplicate.